# Progressbar in lightbox

Tags: jquery, drupal, progress-bar

I have an animated progress bar and i want to show it on lightbox using onclick event in drupal. So that when i click on submit button it shows a progress bar inside the lightbox.

Please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightbox generally uses a CSS class to place the progress indicator. Look in the CSS for lightbox for the class, then create an identical, new class in your theme stylesheet that overrides the class in lightbox.CSS.